# What is the minimum bank angle that an older aircraft like the Cessna 172 can apply in a coordinated turn?

Tags: aircraft-performance, maneuverability

Suppose the weather conditions are favorable and there are no significant winds. The Cessna with a speed of 200km/h starts a coordinated turn with a bank angle of 0.1°

The turning radius of this trajectory would be 180km. (a circular perimeter of 1130Km)

Would it be feasible to apply and hold such a small bank angle to draw such a circle?

When I say feasible, I mean that if there is a possibility that an old aircraft may set a bank angle as small or less than 0.1° in its controls.

Comment: why do you think it would not be feasible? (usefullness aside)

Comment: Just draw the circle on your sectional chart and fly it, keeping the ball centered.  Your average bank angle will be 0.1 degrees.

Comment: This would be entirely theoretical. In reality you will have to compensate your turn for winds aloft so sometimes you would have a much higher bank angle to "draw" a circle on a map.

Comment: When I say feasible, I mean that if there is a possibility that an old aircraft may set a bank angle as small or less than 0.1 ° in its controls.

Comment: "possible to do easily or conveniently..."  Definite no.  What are you actually trying to do?  There's probably a better way.

Comment: While it would be possible to perform the intent of flying a fairly precise arc of 180 km radius (depending on your degree of tolerance), it would not be possible to maintain a precise bank angle of 1° during the entire arc. Regardless of the age of the aircraft. There are too many other factors that would influence the bank angle. Factors such as lateral wind movement, up/down drafts, thrust, airspeed, groundspeed, differential weight, lift and load factors, etc. Even after trimming out the aircraft, these factors would be constantly changing over time.

Comment: Dean, he asked about a tenth of a degree!  P.S.  There is a word for this kind of question - a very precise question about a solution you may have already decided on that is not even the best solution to the root goal...  If you help us understand what you are trying to accomplish you will probably get a flurry of good ideas.  Meanwhile I am going to add to the downvotes because the question doesn't show much forethought.

Comment: In the FAA manuals there is no indication of the maneuver that a pilot must perform to avoid drift caused by the rotation of the earth known as the Coriolis effect. Outside of the FAA manuals there is this proposal: http://walter.bislins.ch/bloge/index.asp?page=How+Airplanes+correct+for+the+Coriolis+Effect Said proposal would imply that the Spirit of St Louis to reach its destination would have required a bank angle of 0.0025 ° sustained throughout its trajectory.

Comment: @MichaelHall - How would you even measure a tenth of a degree of bank? Let alone trim the aircraft for it. Like you, I wonder about the practical purpose of measuring a bank angle that precise. It would be easier and more practical to just to fly a 180 km DME arc (if it can be programmed as such in the OP’s particular aircraft)

Comment: @ElpéndulodeMoisés - There would be no reason to maintain a bank angle of 0.0025° over a transatlantic distance. To give you some perspective, a 0.0025° course deviation would put you off course by one mile over a 24,000 mile course. This is not an exact comparison because 1° bank angle does not exactly equal 1° course deviation. At altitude, I can see a landmark below me offset by more than 1 mile. Even by clock and compass, CL would have plenty of time to correct in a no wind situation. Luck was on his side.

Comment: PS. The reference you cited has this to say, “This bank angle is not noticable. The pilot or autopilot applies this bank angle automatically as he is constantly correcting for any deviation from the planned track. There is no need to plan for such corrections, because they are too small to have any influence on the flight calculations and the necessary corrections for crosswind are bigger and unpredictable.”

Comment: What is the significance of the term "old aircraft"?

Comment: Modern aircraft tend to have more sensitive bank angle displays. Older aircraft do not

Comment: So is this question actually about the Coriolis effect, or are you just using it as an example?  Coriolis effect affects winds, winds affect pilots.  Otherwise we don't care about, or compensate for Coriolis in the way we fly our airplanes.  Ever hear the expression "measure with a micrometer, mark it with a crayon, and cut it with an axe"?

Comment: @ElpéndulodeMoisés - Correction, **newer avionics** tend to be able to be calibrated more precisely. It has nothing to do with the age of the airframe. Aircraft avionics are constantly being retrofitted. On the other hand, the visual display commonly used by the pilot is very standard. The pilot would not see the fine tuned calibration. A pilot flying steam gauges or glass panels would only see a rough indication of bank angle from which they would determine their attitude.

Comment: Case in point. There are 10° & 20° marks on my Attitude Indicator. At my aircraft’s airspeed, I can guess through calculations and know through trial and error to place my bank indicator just a hair past the halfway point of the marks to affect a standard rate turn. But, I can not rely on that alone. I have to cross check that with a clock and a Directional Gyro (compass if necessary). And, that is with modern avionics.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not feasible.  It is not feasible to sustain 1 degree of bank, let alone one tenth of that.  There is no angle of bank indicator that precise, and even if there were it is not possible to maintain that level of accuracy for such an extended period of time.

For an example, ask yourself this:  is it "feasible" for you to hold your fingertip exactly .001" from the tip of your nose for 2 hours?  (Maintaining an air gap, not using a feeler gauge...)  Of course not.  It is not realistic to expect that kind of accuracy and inevitably you would sometimes touch.

However, you can reasonably meet the intent of keeping your finger fairly close.  Or of flying a fairly precise arcing ground track if that is your goal.

For another example, assuming you have a driver's license and drive on high speed interstate highways, pay attention the next time you are on a gently arcing curve and see how much your steering wheel actually moves to hold the road.  It doesn't.  Not perceptibly.  Not at 60MPH on a very gradual bend in the road.  You simply hold it steady and make miniscule adjustments to stay in your lane.

Same thing in an airplane.  You cannot hardly even detect one degree of angle of bank, you simply make fine and continuous adjustments to maintain track.  (And sometimes a degree or two of bank is needed just to keep a straight course!)

As it has been pointed out, you are looking at this backwards:  It is very easy to fly an arcing path, but you wouldn't do it in the manner you suggest.

Comment: Yes.  Humans, and probably most other animals, usually don't maintain precise anything.  They work by feedback, constantly correcting position &c.  It's the same as maintaining say a 10% bank angle: you constantly apply minor corrections.

Comment: @jamesqf . . . . the difference being that 10deg + or - 1deg is still 9deg to 11deg but 0.1deg + or - 1deg is +1.1deg to -0.9deg and -0.9 means you're banked and turning in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have heard that even in conditions where there are no crosswind components in straight and level flight, commercial aircraft must constantly move the nose 1 ° or 2 ° to the right and left. This is also done by banking to make small coordinated turns or only with the tail rudder? And what is the purpose of this maneuver?

Comment: If you try to drive a car or ride a bike in a straight line you will need to make small adjustments, right?  You cannot just freeze things and expect it to track perfectly straight.  Or move the steering wheel once and hold it steady, expecting to perfectly track a curve in the road with no additional corrections needed.  Why do you think it would be any different in an airplane?

Comment: There are many differences in the physics of a car moving on a road and in the physics of an airplane moving through the air mass but I agree that corrections are necessary. I just wanted to know if this type of correction had a specific name and what would happen in practice if this horizontal movement of the nose is avoided for a certain time (obviously in ideal atmospheric conditions). So, assuming these constant corrections were unavoidable, I suppose that would be another reason why it would be unfeasible to sustain a 1 ° bank angle for long, even without considerable crosswind components

Comment: The corrections are called "staying on course" and "staying on altitude.  Yes, I know there is more to flying than driving a car.  I was trying to explain in a context that a non pilot could relate to.  (I assume you are not a pilot...)

Comment: @El péndulo de Moisés: I've no experience of commercial aircraft, but in a small aircraft like the 172 (especially older ones) there is probably more than one or two degrees of play in the control cables & bearings of the ailerons & rudder.  Just as there's play in your car's steering: if you're stopped, you can turn the steering wheel through some angle without moving the tires.